# Trying to initialize array objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

So I know my problem is that my transfer array is not being initialized correctly. Where should I put transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];?

```
@interface PictureViewController (){

    Poi *labelPoi;

}

@end

@implementation PictureViewController
@synthesize imageX;
@synthesize imageY;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize transfer;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

       // transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.imageX = imageX;
        self.imageY = imageY;
        self.name = name;
    }

    return self;
}


/*-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if(self){

        transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.imageX = imageX;
        self.imageY = imageY;
        self.name = name;
        NSLog(@"imageX: %f", self.imageX);
        NSLog(@"imageY: %f", imageY);
        NSLog(@"name: %@", name);

    }
    return self;
}*/

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSLog(@"transfer count: %lu",(unsigned long)transfer.count);
    for(int i = 0; i < transfer.count; i++){
        UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake([[transfer objectAtIndex:i] imageLocationX], [[transfer objectAtIndex:i] imageLocationY], 200, 50)];
        label.text = [[transfer objectAtIndex:i] name];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        NSLog(@"asdfasdsd");
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (id)display:(double)imageXX andY:(double)imageYY withName:(NSString *)namee{
    NSLog(@"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    NSLog(@"imageX: %f",imageXX);
    NSLog(@"imageY: %f", imageYY);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", namee);

    labelPoi = [[Poi alloc] init];
    //transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    labelPoi.imageLocationX = imageXX;
    labelPoi.imageLocationY = imageYY;
    labelPoi.name = namee;
    [transfer addObject:labelPoi];
    NSLog(@"label.x: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationX, imageXX);
    NSLog(@"label.y: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationY, imageYY);
    NSLog(@"label.name: %@ should be: %@",labelPoi.name,namee);
    NSLog(@"transssssfer: %lu", (unsigned long)transfer.count);

    NSLog(@"asfddfsaasfdfdsfsd %f", [[transfer objectAtIndex:0] imageLocationX]);

    return self;
}

@end
```

The Poi object is made up of an imageLocationX, imageLocationY, and name and I am trying to put the Poi object into an array named transfer however, whenever I try to access transfer elements, I receive 0 or null. The (id)display function is being called several times from a different view NSMutable alloc in that function, the array gets reset.

Here is the output:

```
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] imageX: 224.485718
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] imageY: 116.353401
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] name: Beutel Student Health Center
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] label.x: 224.485718 should be: 224.485718
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] label.y: 116.353401 should be: 116.353401
2013-07-19 11:22:06.736 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] label.name: Beutel Student Health Center should be: Beutel Student Health Center
2013-07-19 11:22:06.737 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] transssssfer: 0
2013-07-19 11:22:06.737 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] asfddfsaasfdfdsfsd 0.000000
2013-07-19 11:22:06.737 AR_UAV_App[12466:11303] #############################################################
```

EDIT: .h file

```
@interface PictureViewController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *transfer;
}

@property (nonatomic) double imageX;
@property (nonatomic) double imageY;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *transfer;
- (IBAction)backView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)load:(id)sender X:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name;

-(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name;
-(id)display:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

Comment: put the  transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; after [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `transfer`? I have never seen `@synthesize` without `@property`, so not sure what the behavior is for this.

Comment: Please, add your header code, because even if there is a property `transfer`, you should access it by `_transfer`.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to do the init of transfer where you have it, but your initWithLabel should be calling `[self init]`, not `[super init]`.

Comment: putting transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; after the [super viewDidLoad] will not working because the objects are put into the array before the screen is loaded.  I edited my question to include the header file.

Answer (score 2):

This init method should become the "designated" initializer:

`-(id)initWithLabel:andY:withName:(NSString *)name`

(by the way, it's not named correctly according the [naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html))

The [designated initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) shall initialize the instance properly (that is, in your case it may initialize the array *transfer*, unless you use a [lazy accessor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) ).

The "designated initializer" is most often the "most specialized" initializer - that is, that one with the *most* parameters. Most often, there is *only one* and easily identifiable designated initializer.

The "designated initializer" has the canonical form:

```
-(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        // initialization
        ...
    }
}
```

Other init methods like the `init` method shall invoke the designated initializer like:

```
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithLabel:0 andY:0 withName:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess one problem can be that when you are creating this controller you are calling to:

```
 -(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name
```

In case you do that, you are calling to `[super init]` what will never go through the init method of your class (where you allocated the array). In case you have different methods to init a controller I recommend you to have a:

```
commonInit{
   _transfer = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];
}
```

Then call this method for every init  method that you have in your controller so you ensure that array is allocated.
Other thing is just allocate your array in the `viewDidLoad` of your controller.

Just for making know, you can "allocated" an array without having to take care about release the object by calling to `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];`

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing your PictureViewController with `-(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name`?  If so, I can tell you what the problem is...

```
-(id)initWithLabel:(double)imageX andY:(double)imageY withName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];   // <--- You are likely confused about this line

    .....
}
```

`[super init]` does not pass a message to your custom `-(id)init` method.  It instead is referring to `PictureViewController`'s superclass, which is likely UIViewController.

Your problem should be fixed by uncommenting `transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in the `initWithLabel:` custom init method.

Comment: initWithLabel should be doing `[self init]`, not `[super init]`.

Comment: Yes, that just about summarizes my post haha.  Or, just moving the code.

Answer (score -1):

make a property (synthesize it @synthesize transfer=_transfer;), use lazy instantiation like:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)transfer
{
   if (!_transfer)
   {
       _transfer=[NSMutableArray array];
   }

   return _transfer;
}
```

and take it out of your init